# Add one more data to the magento 2 eav_entity_type table

Tags: magento2.2, eav-attributes

I am trying to add `quote_address` resource  model to the `eav_entity_type` table, and add two `eav_attribute` to it, but not being able to do it.

Following is my UpgradeData file under the setup folder of my module:

```
<?php

namespace Epw\FutureDelivery\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if ($context->getVersion() && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.1') < 0) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $params = [
        'entity_type_code' => 'quote_address',
        'entity_model' => \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Address::class,
        'attribute_model' => null,
        'entity_table' => 'quote_address',
        'value_table_prefix' => null,
        'entity_id_field' => null,
        'increment_model' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue::class,
        'increment_per_store' => 1,
        'increment_pad_length' => 8,
        'increment_pad_char' => 0,
        'additional_attribute_table' => null,
        'entity_attribute_collection' => null,
        ];
        $eavSetup->addEntityType('quote_address', $params);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Address::ENTITY,
                    'carrier_instruction',
                    [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Carrier Instruction',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 1,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
                    'group' => 'quote Details',
                    ]
            );

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Address::ENTITY,
                    'future_delivery_date',
                    [
                    'type' => 'date',
                    'label' => 'Future Delivery Date',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 1,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
                    'group' => 'quote Details',
                    ]
            );

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::ENTITY,
                'carrier_instruction',
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Carrier Instruction',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 1,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
                    'group' => 'Order Details',
                ]
            );

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::ENTITY,
                'future_delivery_date',
                [
                    'type' => 'date',
                    'label' => 'Future Delivery Date',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 1,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
                    'group' => 'Order Details',
                ]
            );

        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?